# Django project in docker container unable to run manage.py runserver

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, docker

I'm new to docker, and struggle a bit to wrap my head around container/image/service concept. I am unable to start container with django image. Here is my Docker file:

```
FROM python:3.6
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /django-ex
COPY /django-ex /django-ex
WORKDIR /django-ex
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

'Build' works fine no errors. But 'up' fails with error:

```
web_1  | python: can't open file '/django-ex/manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
maria-ra-staff_web_1 exited with code 2
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/django-ex
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

I don't understand why 'up' doesn't have my project files. Did I miss something in the process?

EDIT: Build output:

```
db uses an image, skipping
Building web
Step 1/6 : FROM python:3.6
 ---> 5bf410ee7bb2
 Step 2/6 : ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
  ---> Running in 2815482f2d9d
 Removing intermediate container 2815482f2d9d
  ---> a56843c06131
 Step 3/6 : RUN mkdir /django-ex
  ---> Running in 8c6a4a63c266
 Removing intermediate container 8c6a4a63c266
  ---> 8ffbdb670dbb
 Step 4/6 : COPY /django-ex /django-ex
  ---> c314f8e07aae
 Step 5/6 : WORKDIR /django-ex
  ---> Running in 15f0109d52cd
 Removing intermediate container 15f0109d52cd
  ---> 06b4e86e58f8
 Step 6/6 : RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
  ---> Running in eaa9782e1e9b
 {pip install output}
 Successfully installed django-1.11.26 django-debug-toolbar-1.8 gunicorn-19.4.5 psycopg2-2.7.3.1 pytz-2019.3 sqlparse-0.3.0 whitenoise-3.3.1
 Removing intermediate container eaa9782e1e9b
  ---> f22db286d5e3
```

Comment: What's the build output?

Comment: A good first step would be to `docker-compose run web bash` and look around to see what's actually there.  Your `volumes:` statement is hiding the code built into your image and that's a potential source of trouble if it seems like files are missing.

Comment: Why are you using mounts as in `.:/django-ex`? This will hide all the contents of `/django_ex` directory inside container with whatever you have in the compose file's directory. As an example, drop `.:/django-ex` and set `.:/django-ex-2` instead and then see.

Comment: Added build output to question.

Comment: Tried 'docker-compose run web bash', result:

     Starting maria-ra-staff_db_1 ... done                                                                                   root@a833ed9684d1:/django-ex# ls

All files are there in /django-ex folder

Comment: Changed volumes to django-ex-2, new up output says that i have '14 unapplied migration' and i need to run 'migrate' command, where do I add it? In docker-compose.yml?

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know how, but changing folder name in volume to '/django-ex-2' helped. now build and up works fine (I added 'migrate' to Dockerfile). Thank you.

P.S. I won't accept this answer. Maybe someone will explain why it helped.